# how to correctly use variables in vimrc

Tags: vim

I want the vim plugin `CtrlP` to search in my `working_directory` when I hit Ctrl+E, I have the following lines in `.vimrc`

```
let working_directory ="/home/username/website/blog"
noremap <C-e> :CtrlP &working_directory<CR>
```

It doesn't work. How to correctly use the `working_directory` variable to make it work?

Comment: Maybe you can get better help over at: http://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:execute` and concatenation to insert an expression in your mapping:

```
execute "nnoremap <C-e> :CtrlP " . working_directory . "<CR>"
```

Or you can use the expression register:

```
nnoremap <C-e> :CtrlP <C-r>=working_directory<CR><CR>
```